Ceph erasure coding issue
See I have total host 5, each host holding 24 HDD and each HDD is of size 9.1TiB.
So, a total of 1.2PiB out of which i am getting 700TiB.
I did erasure coding 3+2 and placement group 128.
But, the issue i am facing is when I turn off one node write is completely disabled. Erasure coding 3+2 can handle two nodes failure but it’s not working in my case.
I request this community to help me tackle this issue.
The min size is 3 and 4 pools in total
I tried by turning down one host and the write got completely blocked.

What is the database tag for? I recommend to ask your question at https://serverfault.com. And when you do, add more information like ceph osd pool ls detail, ceph osd tree, ceph osd crush rule dump {APPLIED_RULE}, ceph osd erasure-code-profile get {APPLIED_PROFILE}.

Is your crush-failure-domain set to host or osd?
